# Html modification using JSOUP - Don't want my url to be "resolved"

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Here is my issue : I want to modify an html file on my tomcat server.
This file isn't showed by clients, it is destinated to an embedded system.

My file `index.html`, juste needs to have a list updated (just adding some html elements with a for loop.. pretty simple).

Here is the problem, when `Jsoup.parse()`, Jsoup resolves UI, and I don't want it !! I want it to leave me do whatever I want.
I'm getting mad because I can't find a way to avoid that.

Here is my code (it's dirty, school project rush :( ):

```
public String updateIndex(List<Article> articleList)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("embedded/index.html");
            Document content = Jsoup.parse(in, "utf-8", "azaze");
            Elements articleListElements = content.select("div.aritcle-list");
            for (Element articleListElement : articleListElements)
            {
                for (Article article : articleList)
                {
                    Element articleItem = articleListElement.appendElement("div");
                    articleItem.addClass("article-list-item");
                    articleItem.addClass("row");

                    Element articleLinkElement = articleItem.appendElement("a");
                    articleLinkElement.attr("href", "LOOOL");

                    Element articleTitleElement = articleLinkElement.appendElement("h3");
                    articleTitleElement.append(article.getTitle());

                    Element articleDescriptionElement = articleItem.appendElement("div");
                    articleDescriptionElement.addClass("article-list-item-description");
                    articleDescriptionElement.append(article.getDescription());
                }
            }
            LOGGER.info("base URI =" + content.baseUri());
            return content.toString();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**NOTE :** Changing the uri in `Document content = Jsoup.parse(in, "utf-8", "azaze");` does not change anything. And I juste want JSOUP to leave url's alone :).

Example of not desiredtransformation :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/GiveMeAShow/update/css/bootstrap.css">
```

How to avoid that ?

Thank you !

Comment: I don't think Jsoup does that. Could you please share your html?

Comment: I don't see how the example tranformation has anything to do with your code. You aren't even accessing any `<link>` element. Anyway, are you positive that the HTML doesn't contain absolute URLs in the first place? `element.attr("href")` should only yield the `href` attribute as defined in the HTML source. My guess is that the source already contains absolute URLs. You can parse them and remove the host as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html).